# I have to show this polynomial is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose that $p(x)=x^9+x^8+x^4+x^2+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. I have to show this polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: "A manual check shows that this polynomial is not divisible by any of the 256 polynomials of lower degree. Therefore, it is irreducible."

What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

If the polynomial is reducible, it must have an irreducible factor of degree at most $4$.  It is clear by the Factor Theorem that $p$ has no factors of degree $1$.  There is one irreducible quadratic in ${\Bbb Z}_2[x]$, there are two irreducible cubics and three irreducible quartics.  Try them all.

Source for numbers: well known, or http://oeis.org/A001037.

**Comment**.  As we are working in ${\Bbb Z}_2[x]$ with polynomials of degree less than $10$, you can do the calculations by counting on your fingers.  **This is not a joke**, it really is possible - try it!!!

Comment: why it must have an irreducible factor of degree at most 4?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: @armin If it has an irreducible factor of degree $>4$, the quotient has degree $\le 4$, so you'd already have found its irreducible factors. It's the same as when we look for prime factors of an integer $n$: if we reach above $\sqrt{n}$ without finding one, then we conclude that $n$ is prime.

Comment: can you explain more about there is one irreducible quadratic and  there are two irreduvible cubics?

Comment: There is a good discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32197.

Comment: @ thank's a lot