# Abstract Algebra - Congruence Class Roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences

How do we find the roots of ${x^3 + x + 1}$ in $ {Z_2[x]} $

The elements of the congruence class are: $$0, 1, x, x + 1, x^2, x^2 + 1, x^2 + x, x^2 + x + 1$$ as they have to be of the form $ax^2 + bx + c \in Z_2$.

However, I am unable to find the roots.

Specifically, I am unsure why $x^2$ and $x^2 + x + 1$ are roots in $x^3 + x + 1$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by the roots of a ring?

Comment: Perhaps he means [one of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_a_ring).

Comment: $x^2$ is not a "root" in $x^3+x+1$.

Comment: Apologies for my foggy understanding. I actually have to show that  {Z_2[x]}/ {x^3 + x + 1} is a field, hence I am trying to find the roots.

Comment: The question is terribly formulated. What he probably means is that, if $I=(x^3+x+1)$ is the ideal generated by that polynomial, then $x^2+I$ and $x^2+x+1+I$ are roots of the polynomial in the quotient. Btw, is that quotient a field? Yes it is: $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible.

Comment: $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible, as it has no roots over $\mathbb{F}_2$. So the quotient is a field.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32197/find-all-irreducible-monic-polynomials-in-mathbbz-2x-with-degree-equal) for more information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Older Answer left as extra**

If I take you correctly, what you are after are the roots of the polynomial $t^3+t+1$ viewed as an element of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3+x+1)}[t]$. Let me name that ideal $I$. You are asking why $x^2+I$ and $x^2+x+1+I$ are roots. Let us just substitute those roots into the polynomial $f(t)=t^3+t+1$, shall we?
\begin{align*}
f(x^2)={}&x^6+x^2+1=x^2(-x^2-x)-x^2+1=-x^4-x^3-x^2+1={} \\
{}={}&x^2+x+x+1-x^2+1=0,
\end{align*}
definitely a root then, and:
\begin{align*}
f(x^2+x+1)={}&(x^2+x+1)^3+x^2+x+1+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^4+x^2+1)+x^2+x={} \\
{}={}&x^6+x^4+x^2+x^5+x^3+x+x^4+x^2+1+x^2+x={} \\
{}={}&x^2(-x^2-x)-x^2-x+x^2+x(-x^2-x)-x-1+x-x^2-x+x^2+1+x^2+x={} \\
{}={}&x^2+x+x+1-x^2-x+x^2+x(-x^2-x)-x-1+x-x^2-x+x^2+1+x^2+x={} \\
{}={}&1-x+x^2-x^2+x+1-x-1+x-x^2-x+x^2+1+x^2+x={} \\
{}={}&-x-1+x-x^2-x+x^2+1+x^2+x=-1-x+1+x^2=-1,
\end{align*}
definitely not a root then. $x$ is the another root, as always in this kind of quotients. As noted by Bernard, the last root is close to the one tried above: it's $x^2+x$:
\begin{align*}
f(x^2+x)={}&(x^2+x)^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2+x)(-x^2-x+x^2)+x^2+x+1={} \\
{}={}&-x^3-x^2+x^2+x+1=-x^3+x+1=x+1+x+1=0.
\end{align*}
Let us now factor the polynomial since we have its three roots:
$$f(t)=(t-x)(t-x^2-x)(t-x^2).$$
In carrying out my calculations, I used the fact that:
\begin{align*}
x^4=x\cdot x^3=x(-x-1)=-x^2-x, && x^3=-x-1, \\
\begin{aligned}
x^6=x^2\cdot x^4={}&x^2(-x^2-x)=-x^4-x^3={} \\
{}={}&x^2+x+x+1=x^2+1
\end{aligned} && \begin{aligned}
x^5={}&x\cdot x^4=x(-x^2-x)={} \\
{}={}&x+1-x^2=x^2+x+1
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
which is because $x^3+x+1=0$ in your quotient field.

**End of old answer which answers actual question, with a little addition**

Yes indeed, this is a field, since the polynomial generating $I$ is clearly irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, as it has no roots. We could have seen that from the start, but now that we have the 3 roots in the quotient we see none of them is in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Also, this quotient is the splitting field of that polynomial.

$f(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ since $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$, and $f(0)=0^2+0+1=1$ and $f(1)=1^2+1+1=1+1+1=0+1=1$. It is a third-degree polynomial, so having no roots implies being irreducible, as if it were reducible it would have to factor as a first-degree polynomial times a second-degree one, and hence have a root. Being $f$ irreducible, the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ with respect to $I=(f(x))$ is a field.

Comment: Well then my answer answers two questions in one, his one being answered by «none of them in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ at the end :).

Comment: Thank you very much! My apologies in advance for my ignorance, however I am unsure how you obtained the following: \begin{align*}
f(x^2)={}&x^6+x^2+1=x^2(-x^2-x)-x^2+1 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: I divided {x^6 + x^2 + 1} by {x^3 + x + 1} and I'm afraid I did not obtain that.

Comment: The actual root is $x^2+x$, I must have miscalculated something. Edit coming soon :). See also comments to other answer.

Comment: Anyway remember that in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ a sum of squares is the square of the sum, so $x^6+x^2+1=(x^3)^2+x^2+1=(x^3+x+1)^2$.

Comment: Oh thanks, that totally makes sense now.

Comment: My apologies for pestering you one last time, but how did you obtain the following: x^6=x^2(-x^2-x)

Comment: $x^6=x^2\cdot x^4$, now if you're convinced about the value for $x^4$ you should be done.

Comment: @abstract perhaps the edit will shed more light.

Comment: This is truly amazing - thanks so much for your help! It makes complete sense now.

Comment: Glad I could help. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean finding the other roots of $x^3+x+1$ in $\mathbf F_8=\mathbf Z_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$, in addition to the class $\omega$ of $x$?

$\omega^2$ is another root, because of the *Frobenius* morphism:
$$(\omega^2)^3+\omega^2+1=(\omega^3+\omega+1)^2=0.$$
The sum of the roots is $0$,so the third root is the sum of the first two: $\,\omega^2+\omega$.

If you mean finding the roots of $x^3+x+1$ in $\mathbf Z_2$, there are none, as is easily checked, hence the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbf Z_2[x]$ (a reducible polynomial of degree $3$ in a field has a root in that field).

Comment: It might be more clear if you did not use the same symbol for the variable of the ring and for the polynomial.

Comment: The OP says " I actually have to show that $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$ is a field, hence I am trying to find the roots". So I think, he just wants to find the roots of $x^3+x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: this was not clear to me, but it's a possible interpretation indeed.

Comment: How come my calculations tell me $x^2+x+1$ is a root and I read $x^2+x$ is? Substituting $x^2+x$ in the polynomial, I get (of Wolfram gets) $x^6+3x^5+3x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, and $x^6=x^2(-x^2-x)=x^2+x+x+1=x^2+1$, $x^5=x(-x^2-x)=x+1-x=1$, $x^4=-x^2-x$ and $x^3=-x-1$, which, brought into Wolfram, yields $x^2-x+2$, which modulo 2 is $x^2-x≠0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your value for $x^5$ is false: I find $x^2+x+1$.  Your way of calculating is very heavy: don't forget in $\mathbf Z_2$, $-1=1=3.

Comment: You're right, I mis-multiplied and had a $-x$ instead of a $-x^2$. With that, I do get your value. Will edit my own answer.

Comment: Why do you state the sum of the roots must be zero?

Comment: Because the coefficient of $x^2$ in the equation is $0$(see relations between elementary symmetric functions of the roots and coefficients).