# Find all irreducible polynomials of degrees $2$ and $3$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{2}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, polynomial-rings

> Find all irreducible polynomials of degrees $2$ and $3$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{2}[x]$.

I tried to follow (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32416)'s answer but this part in their answer I do not understand:

> A polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $2$ or $3$ is irreducible if and only if it does not have linear factors.  Therefore, it suffices to show that $p(0) = p(1) = 1$.  This quickly tells us that $x^2 + x + 1$ is the only irreducible polynomial of degree $2$.  This also tells us that $x^3 + x^2 + 1$ and $x^3 + x + 1$ are the only irreducible polynomials of degree $3$.

The part I don't understand is "it suffices to show $p(0)=p(1)=1$". Could someone please explain what this means and how this finds the irreducible polynomials?

Comment: If you are looking for irreducible polynomial of degree 3 or 2 in a fieldYou just have to show it has no zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the "if and only if" statement as follows.

> A polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $2$ or $3$ is reducible if and only if it has linear factor.

By the factor theorem,

> $p(x)$ has linear factor iff $p(0) = 0$ or $p(1) = 0$.

Take the negation on both sides.

> $p(x)$ has no linear factor iff $p(0) \ne 0$ and $p(1) \ne 0$.

Since we are in $\Bbb{Z}_2$, the RHS can be simply written as follows.

> $p(x)$ has no linear factor iff $p(0) = p(1) = 1$.
>
> ---

In $\Bbb{Z}_2[X]$,

- $p(0) = 1$ iff the constant term is $1$.
- $p(1) = 1$ iff the polynomial contains odd number of terms.

This helps us to select the irreducible polynomials of degree $\le 3$ by eliminating those with even number of terms and/or no constant term.

Comment: Thank you for giving a very clear answer, I understand now... the $0$ and $1$ are elements in $\Bbb{Z}_{2}$. But how does this theorem find the irreducible polynomials?

Comment: @numericalorange I've [edit]ed my answer to explain how to use $p(0)$ and $p(1)$ to check irreducibility of $p$.  The [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) allows us to find linear factors of a polynomial by substituting values into the indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting read!